# How to check if array length is increasing or not after input select2

Tags: javascript, html

I have input name using select2 like below

```
<select class="form-control" name="name" multiple="multiple" id="name" style="width:100% !important;">
</select>
```

Right now, If the user want to add 10 name simultaneously, if user typed `name` , if `name` value typed in `number 8` is same with their `name` typed in `number 3` before it will not enter to `select2` val.

Next, I want to add `alert` in case above, so after user typed `name` , if `name` value typed in `number 8` is same with their `name` typed in `number 3` before, it shows alert.

I've tried using `array.length` to check, if `array.length` is not increased, it shows `alert`, but the `alert` is not show in my code.

Here's the code

```
 $('#name').on('change', function(){
       var a= $("#name").val();
       var b = a.length;
       if(b!=b+1)
       {
          alert(test)
       }
 })
```